# Can a GQL query execute an order by over two or more kinds?

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, datastore, gqlquery

I have two entity kinds in my python GAE app - both with similar attributes - and I'd like to query both lists and order the result according to an attribute common to both kinds.  So something along the lines of:

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Video1, Video2 ORDER BY views DESC").fetch(1000)
```

Can I do this in GQL directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You need to run two queries, one for each kind.

Check out the [GQL](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) and [GqlQuery class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html) references.

You can actually do a kindless query using db.GqlQuery('SELECT') to fetch everything.  However, you can not filter or order it (other than by **key**).

**edit**:

You may want to check out [PolyModel](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass.html).